# Why is my async function not working? I just want it to console.log the results of the mongodb query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I keep getting  Promise { < pending > } on the console.log, I am not too experienced at all with Async functions. (Using JavaScript, Node, Mongodb)

```
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          // return result;
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  var result = await resolveAfter1();
}

asyncCall();

console.log(asyncCall());
```

Comment: you will have `result` as the resolved value inside your `asyncCall()` function

Comment: Your log for `asyncCall()` will be just undefined as the function is not returning anything.

Comment: All functions marked with the `async` keyword return promises. That's what the `async` keyword do - it is a promise constructor with the added feature that you can use the `await` keyword inside it. So to `console.log` you need to call it like a regular promisified function: `asyncCall().then(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: Like this?        `async function asyncCall() {
  var result = await resolveAfter1();
  return result;
}`

Comment: Thank you all for feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `async` function from non async context, it's same as using a promise.

IE. this:

```
async function something() {return 0;}

var result = something();
```

is almost the same as this:

```
function something() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{resolve(0);});
}

var result = something();
```

In both cases, `result` will be a `Promise`, you can try it in console.

This means, that if you want to get the result, you need to do it from `async` function:

```
async function asyncCall() {
  var result = await resolveAfter1();
  console.log(result);
}
```

To access async result from since context, you still need to go with good 'ol `.then` and `.catch`:

```
resolveAfter1()
    .then((result)=>{console.log(result);})
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);})
```

Additionally, you should NOT throw in promise, that's what `reject` is for:

```
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) 
              reject(err);
          else
              resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this finally shows the values on the console.log

Answer (score 0):

```
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          // return result;
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  var result = await resolveAfter1();
  console.log(result); // here's your result
  return result;
}

asyncCall().then(result => console.log(result));

// console.log(asyncCall());
```